# What is the nameserver to use for heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am hosting my app at heroku, my domain is with godaddy. How to point my domain to my heroku app?

Shall I change NameServer 1 and NameServer 2 to myApp.herokuapp.com and myApp.herokuapp.com?

I have followed instructions at heroku, but, I want to make sure that I am on the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change the nameservers, Heroku is not a DNS provider. You leave the domain management wherever you are comfortable with it and edit the records to point at your app on Heroku.

It's detailed more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#dns-setup but in summary, if you have a domain foobah.com registered with GoDaddy with would use their control panel (maybe Advanced control panel) to edit the DNS records to point at Heroku. You need to have a CNAME record for www.foobah.com with it's value set to myapp.herokuapp.com. You may find you already have an A record setup for you when you registered the domain or an existing site, you should delete this. You also then need to add the custom domain www.foobah.com to your application on Heroku.